# Please identify this rose growing in my garden

Tags: identification, roses

Can someone please identify this rose?[image]

Answer (score 2):

It could be a Grandiflora rose. Or even a bella. Its hard to say without completely looking at it. My pink roses climb up the front of my house up to my kitchen window. Some vine out some bush up, thorn sizes and color can be different aswell. Take in account how it grows how its pattern is.

Could even be a Pergola or nohelia rose, mine are a varient of Blaze rose, They are slightly darker climbing roses and vine out.